# Can I update my model or other classes from inside an actionfilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following actionfilter:

```
public class PopulateMetaAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)   
    {
        var a = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model. ???
        return;
    }
}
```

I would like to update my model or a class that is defined in the action that just caused the action filter to run. What I tried to do was code the line starting with var a. All worked okay until I got to the word Model and then intellisense didn't give me any suggestion on fields.

Am I going about this the right way. I thought if I choose the OnActionExecuted then the fields in my method would be available.

Can someone explain if I can access this model data or if I can update fields in classes in my action method.

Comment: Since you're going to need a cast, I think it's better to define an Interface for your models (IMetaModel) with appropriate setters/getters on MetaProperties. This will make your attribute reusable across different models implementing the very same interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you will need to cast it. For example:

```
var a = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as MyViewModel;
if (a != null)
{
    a.MyProperty = ...;
}
```

Comment: This would be very good if it works. I will try it out and update mark the answer hopefully soon.

Comment: Here's an article with an example using an ActionFilter and Interfaces to add page meta data: http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Adding-page-meta-data-with-a-custom-action-filter.aspx